# PHP everything okay but i am not getting order no that generated it shows in script alert not in sms/ Message

Tags: php, mysql

> Here is all the details....

```
<?php
include 'configdb.php';
$Name=$_POST['Name'];
$Mobile=$_POST['Mobile'];
$From=$_POST['From'];
$To=$_POST['To'];
$Date=$_POST['Date'];
$Time=$_POST['Time'];
$Person=$_POST['Person'];
$conn=mysqli_connect($mysqlhost,$mysqlusername,$mysqlpassword,$mysqldb);
if(!$conn) {die("Connection failed:".mysqli_connect_error());}
$sql="INSERT INTO BOOKING (NAME,MOBILE) VALUES ('$Name','$Mobile')";
if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
    echo"record inserted";
} else {
    echo "Error:".$sql."<br>".mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

> Succesfully script showing Order no from table BOOKING

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo("<script>alert(\"Thank You...$Name...Your Order no is :- ".$row["ORDER_NO"]."\");</script>");
    }
}
//API Servise Start
$authKey = "API Key";
$mobileNumber = "$Mobile";$senderId = "MCIBQA";
```

> In $message not getting My Order no in SMS that generated but showing in script alert

```
$message = urlencode("Order placed Name-$Name OrderNo-".$row["ORDER_NO"]." No-$Mobile");$route = "4"; 
$postData = array(
'authkey' => $authKey,
'mobiles' => $mobileNumber,
'message' => $message,
'sender' => $senderId,
'route' => $route);
```

Comment: Question is absolutely unclear. Please edit it, stating what you're trying to achive.

Answer (score 0):

When you access the $row-Variable to get the Order-Number for your message, it does not contain that information any more.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // $row contains data
    // Build the message here
}
// $row is now FALSE, otherwise the while loop would be running still
```

So you have to build the message inside the loop.